# Can't connect to MySQL container on AWS ECS

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ecs

I can't seem to connect to a MySQL container in AWS ECS. Here's the docker-compose.yml I'm using with `ecs-cli compose up`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: "mylogs"
        awslogs-region: "us-east-2"
        awslogs-stream-prefix: "db"
    mem_limit: 300000000

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: "mylogs"
        awslogs-region: "us-east-2"
        awslogs-stream-prefix: "web"
    mem_limit: 300000000
```

The error I get it is:

```
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22 
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
```

This seems to work fine locally but not in AWS ECS. Do I need to do something else for AWS?

Comment: May be you have to open the port in your associated security group on aws?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to open up the port since the WordPress container is on the same machine as the MySQL container. Here's the example from the AWS docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html#example_task_definition-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The `depends_on` field is [not supported in ECS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html). Your `wordpress` container is starting before your `db` container opens its port, hence the error.

You'll need to introduce a wrapper script to wait for the port to become available.